# Recalculate WPF DatePicker value to specific Noda Time DateTimeZone

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datepicker, nodatime

I'm using Noda Time library in my project to work with Dates. But I need to allow user to enter date/time using DatePicker in specific Noda timezone (non utc, non local/system). How can I achieve that?

Currently I binded my DatePicker to DateTime property and converting this value in property setter to unspecified kind

```
public DateTime SessionDate
{
   get 
   { 
      return _sessionDate; 
   }
   set 
   { 
       _sessionDate = new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified); 
       OnPropertyChanged("SessionDate"); 
   }
}
```

So, now I have value entered by user represented as DateTime structure with unspecified kind.

But I need to get the UTC value (Noda Instant) from my unspecified SessionDate by applying known DateTimeZone. I tried to use

```
var instant = new Instant(SessionDateTime.Ticks);
var offset = myTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(instant);
instant = instant.PlusTicks(- offset.Ticks);
```

but I'm not sure if this is a good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user is entering time with respect to a specific time zone, then you're not starting with an `Instant`.  You're starting with a `LocalDateTime` and a `DateTimeZone`.  You need to bind those together to get a `ZonedDateTime` before you can get to an `Instant`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(SessionDateTime);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.InZoneLeniently(myTimeZone);
Instant instant = zdt.ToInstant();
```

Comment: Also, in your property, I'm not sure why your assigning ticks, but you can just do `_sessionDate = value;`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test your approach. And I'm using "ticks workaround" because DateTime is immutable and DatePicker returns value with Kind.Local (so to change Kind of DateTime to Unspecified, which better describes my value I'm creating a new DateTime structure with kind specified in the constructor).

Comment: Might be clearer to use `DateTime.SpecifyKind`.  Does the same thing.

Comment: Or, just make the property itself a `LocalDateTime`